# How to access SSL client certificate from rack app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, rack, client-certificates

Actually -- question title tells almost everything. In earlier Rails (2.x) I've seen code that was accessing client certificate details via `request.env` hash. My rack app is receiving `call` with `env` argument, but this data is not there. How can I access it?

Answer (score 1):

You should enable this on web server e.g. in Apache do SSLOptions +ExportCertData and/or +StdEnvVars. So you will get SSL_* vars in env.