# How do you configure a Heroku Rack/Rails app to authenticate the client certificate of an incoming request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, ssl, heroku, rack

Say I have a Web service, called *JokeService*, which is a Rack/Rails3 app deployed on Heroku. And lets say I have an application, called *ComedyApp*. Now, I want *JokeService* to only entertain requests from *ComedyApp*. To do so, I would like *ComedyApp* to use a client certificate, which it uses to authenticate itself with *JokeService*.

My question is, how the heck can I configure the *JokeService* (again, a Rack/Rails3 app on Heroku) to check the validity of the client certificate?

This is related, but unanswered: [How to access SSL client certificate from rack app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726182/how-to-access-ssl-client-certificate-from-rack-app)

Comment: "client certificate, which it includes in the request headers"? What kind of authentication does this provide you with? This doesn't seem to involve any signature... Shouldn't you use the client-cert authentication at the SSL/TLS level instead (which involves a step for the server to verify that the client has the private key for the certificate presented)?

Comment: Bruno, that's actually what I mean. I've edited my writing to remove the ambiguity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, you can't, since we don't have control of the http layer (thin or the routing mesh) in the stack.

An alternative is to authenticate one's requests simply using a custom request header.